# Volatile variable visibility to inner class

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile, anonymous-class

I have a multiple-threaded code with a volatile flag into the class A. The code has an static nested class B and I need to use this volatile flag to a new logic control into the inner class.
However, the volatile variable is not visible from the class B. Any ideas how can I manipulate it?

code example:

```
public class A
{
    public volatile boolean flag = false;

    public static class B
    {
        //What I want to do
        this.flag = true;
    }

}
```

> Problem context overview:  The flag already exists into class A. Its already manipulated by N classes and threads 'at the same time'. Now, I need to add a new logic to the inner class B which will execute ONLY IF the flag is true at the time of a method execution. But, for this, I need to acess the flag variable value.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to be clear, there is no anonymous inner class in your code. class `B` is what's called a `static nested class`.

Comment: And if you want `B` to have access to the members of `A`, all you need to do is convert `B` to an `inner class` by changing its definition to `public class B { ... }`

Comment: Do you know any other way, @Flaom? The code is a lot more complexe than what I shown and the removal of the static status will lead to a lot of problems in other classes that uses the same instance of class B

Comment: I already have a flag in class A which is manipulated by many other classes and threads at the same time. Now, I need to manipulate it from the inner class B as well

Comment: Would it work for your use case to make the flag variable static? That is probably the simplest solution if it will work for you

Comment: @Flaom that's my problem. It's not a single threaded code. I need it to be visible to any thread acessing this class. So, the variable must be volatile and a volatile variable cannot be static.

Comment: *a volatile variable cannot be static* [That's news to me.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#d5e12982) (Not that it's a good idea.)

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- wtf, it works! Thaks dude, i'll take it to life.